# Domain returns 404 with www in url, but works fine without www

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt

I just noticed that certbot has failed the renewal of the SSL certificate on my site.

When running certbot manually I was able to renew the certificate for `1: example.com` but when trying `2: www.example.com` I get the error

```
Failed authorization procedure. www.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Yz4RezbUvNFiGMoUi__MV5-XpmQ3tD2DwSeO4cpxWrw [2607:f8b0:400f:800::2013]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=dev"
```

I also get a 404 error when visiting www.example.com in my browser, but http(s)://example.com works fine.

I'm running the ubuntu droplet from digitalocean with apache.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you get an error by visiting www.example.com, certbot get the same error and so cannot renew the certificate. You have to check your error log file and your apache configuration to see and find what's the problem when you use www.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My log files didn't show anything wrong as far as I can tell. I'm fairly certain I've made a mistake in the apache config, but I don't know what. I followed the guide from digital ocean to set it up. Guess I'm doomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I'm really, really stupid. I had messed up the DNS records.